# how to sync Range-type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 inputs as you see in my code if you type anything in the input/text it shows perfectly fine at range but not the other way around this is my problem
I am also open to completely different approaches to the problem any answer is accepted

Code Snippet:

```js
var city = document.getElementById('city')
var cityrepeat = document.getElementById('cityrepeat')
var state = document.getElementById('state')
var staterepeat = document.getElementById('staterepeat')

function setCity() {
  cityrepeat.value = city.value
}

function setd() {
  city.value = cityrepeat.value
}

function setState() {
  staterepeat.value = state.value
}
```

```html
City    
<input id="city" type="text" onKeyUp="setCity()" size=5/></br>
State
<input id="state" type="text" onKeyUp="setState()" size=5/></br>
City repeat
<input id="cityrepeat" type="range" min="1" max="100"onKeyUp="setd()"/></br> 
State repeat
<input id="staterepeat" type="range"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `onKeyUp="setd()"` use `onchange="setd()"`

```html
<input id="cityrepeat" type="range" min="1" max="100" onchange="setd()"/>
```

**Or even better**:
In order to make the value updating 'live', you can do this:

*in the html:*

```html
<input id="cityrepeat" type="range" min="1" max="100" onmousedown="updating=true;setd()" onmouseup="updating=false"/>
```

*in you script*:

```js
var updating = false

function setd() {
  city.value = cityrepeat.value
  if (updating){
    requestAnimationFrame(setd)
  }
}
```

```js
var city = document.getElementById('city')
var cityrepeat = document.getElementById('cityrepeat')
var state = document.getElementById('state')
var staterepeat = document.getElementById('staterepeat')

var updating = false

function setCity() {
  cityrepeat.value = city.value
}

function setd() {
  city.value = cityrepeat.value
  if (updating){
   requestAnimationFrame(setd)
  }
}

function setState() {
  staterepeat.value = state.value
}
```

```html
City    
<input id="city" type="text" onKeyUp="setCity()" size=5/><br>
State
<input id="state" type="text" onKeyUp="setState()" size=5/><br>
City repeat
<input id="cityrepeat" type="range" min="1" max="100" onmousedown="updating=true;setd()" onmouseup="updating=false"/><br> 
State repeat
<input id="staterepeat" type="range"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `onChange` instead of `onKeyUp` on the slider.

```html
    <input id="cityrepeat" type="range" min="1" max="100"onChange="setd()"/></br>
```

Comment: Wow 1st time someone answers my q correctly. Thank you